# How to phrase the tf.exe branch command?

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I am having difficulty to phrase the command

```
tf.exe branch olditem newitem [/version:versionspec]
```

Especially, I don't know what to put for "versionspec"

I tried this from Powershell:

```
.\Tf.exe branch $/ProjectA/DEV $/ProjectB/DEV1 /workspace
```

but I got the below error:

Unrecognized command option 'workspace'.

Can anybody help me set the full command with an example?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create branch for latest version of your source code you may use branch command without versionspec: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branch-command

> If no version is provided, Team Foundation uses the following logic to decide which version of the item to copy to the new branch:
>
> > •If a Team Foundation version control server path is specified, then Team Foundation branches the item at the latest Team Foundation version control server version. For example, tf branch $/projects/help.cs uses the server version.
> >
> > •If a local path is specified for the source, Team Foundation uses the local, workspace version to create the new branch. For example, tf branch C:\314.cs uses the local workspace version.

Answer (score 0):

The **branch** command copies an item or set of items, including metadata and version control history, from one location to another in the Team Foundation version control server and in the local workspace.

As for what to put for "`versionspec`", please refer below tutorials:

> **Versionspecs**
>
> A versionspec specifies the version of an item that you want to work
>   with.   You can specify versions in a command either by including the
>   versionspec as part of the version option (for example,
>   /version:C1256) or by appending the versionspec to a file name with a
>   semicolon (for example, filename;Lmylabel).
>
> [*Source Link*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56f7w6be#How%20Team%20Foundation%20Parses%20Itemspecs%20and%20Versionspecs)

If you want to specify the workspace, you are lacking a **W** in front of the workspace name. For example: *Workspace* `(Wworkspacename)`

---

A sample full command in cmd with using tf.exe branch command for your reference(my worksace name is PATRICK-W10 in this case):

```
tf branch $/ScrumProject/TestCaseProject  $/ScrumProject/Test  /v:WPATRICK-W10
```

[image]